# How to replace text in repeated fragments inside parent text using re module?

Tags: python, replace, python-re

I have html file, that contains repeated **`code`** tags:

```html
<h3>Post header content</h3>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, delectus.
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam culpa illo necessitatibus 
    officia sed totam. Aspernatur cupiditate debitis eos obcaecati! Dolores eveniet excepturi hic optio.
</p>

<code class="code">
$ pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

</code>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Accusamus et hic neque, suscipit totam ullam.</p>


<code class="code">

// Linux
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development

// Windows
set FLASK_APP=app.py
set FLASK_ENV=development

</code>

<p>More text...</p>
```

I want to find all **`code`** tags, make with them some sting operations and return to source string.
This is a fragment of my code:

```py
import re

def code2replace(code):
    # find all code fragments
    RE_CODE = r'<code[^>]+>(.*?)<\/code>'
    matches = re.finditer(RE_CODE, code, re.S)
    

    rs_text = ''
    code_text = ''
    pos_start = 0

    for match in matches:
        # print(f'Start: {match.start()}, End: {match.end()}, Content: {match.group(1)}')
        code_text = match.group(1).replace('\n', '\n<br/>')

        rs_text += code[pos_start: match.start()] + f'<code class="code">{code_text}</code>'
        pos_start = match.end()

    return rs_text
```

But unfortunately this is not work correctly.

So, how to change content of **`code`** tags inside this html and return changed result?

Comment: Have you considered using a proper HTML parser?

Comment: FWIW I agree with @tobias_k, using regexes to parse HTML is generally considered a poor programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually does seem to work, but it can be simplified significantly by using `re.sub` instead of `re.finditer`, so you do not have to piece together the full text from the start and end positions of the individual matches:

```
def code2replace(html):
    def fix_code(match):
        code = match.group(1).replace("\n", "\n<br>")
        return f'<code class="code">{code}</code>'
    RE_CODE = r'<code[^>]+>(.*?)<\/code>'
    return re.sub(RE_CODE, fix_code, html, flags=re.S)
```

All that could also be done in a single line with a `lambda` but I think it's more readable and more extensible this way. Like your code, this will replace e.g. the first code block with this:

```html
<code class="code">
<br>$ pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
<br>
<br></code>
```

Note that this will also replace any opening `<code>` tag with the same `<code>` tag, ignoring any additional attributes or different `class` values. To keep the original `<code`> tag, you could just `return match.group().replace("\n", "\n<br>")` instead (`group()`, not `group(1)`).

Answer (score 1):

It's working. Annotated in the output(for debugging).

```
0: regex finds this block at first and updates \n with \n<br/>
<br/>$ pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
<br/>
<br/>
1: then regex finds this block and updates \n with \n<br/>
<br/>
<br/>// Linux
<br/>export FLASK_APP=app.py
<br/>export FLASK_ENV=development
<br/>
<br/>// Windows
<br/>set FLASK_APP=app.py
<br/>set FLASK_ENV=development
<br/>
<br/>
```

Full Output:

```
<h3>Post header content</h3>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, delectus.
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam culpa illo necessitatibus
    officia sed totam. Aspernatur cupiditate debitis eos obcaecati! Dolores eveniet excepturi hic optio.
</p>

<code class="code">
<br/>$ pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
<br/>
<br/></code>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Accusamus et hic neque, suscipit totam ullam.</p>


<code class="code">
<br/>
<br/>// Linux
<br/>export FLASK_APP=app.py
<br/>export FLASK_ENV=development
<br/>
<br/>// Windows
<br/>set FLASK_APP=app.py
<br/>set FLASK_ENV=development
<br/>
<br/></code>
```